# When trying to log in the WSO2 IS, I get an authentication error in the browser

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I try to log in to ***MyAccount*** app in ***5.11***, I am getting the following error in `wso2carbon.log`

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-03-04 11:31:28,787] [6b1c0dfe-00f5-485a-9d33-443a4d4790ca] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error at login happens due to the `sessionDataKey` being invalidated during the authentication.

In simple terms, `sessionDataKey` is a query parameter with a unique value which is sent by WSO2 IS until the authentication is completed. Therefore, this value is needed until you provide your credentials and log in to the SP(`MyAccount` app)

The above error can occur in any of the following scenarios.

1. Double submit - If you click the sign-in button more than one time, the same `sessionDataKey` will be submitted to `/commonauth` endpoint more than once and it will cause the above error.
2. Bookmarking the page - If you have bookmarked the login page with an already expired `sessionDataKey` value, you will be submitting that value every time and that will cause the above error.
3. Clicking the browser back button - If you submit the same `sessionDataKey` value by going back in the browser, the above error will occur as well.

All of the above scenarios can be pinpointed with `<IS_HOME>/repository/logs/http_access<DATE>.log` file.

1. If you are seeing multiple `POST` requests to `/commonauth` endpoint, the issue is due to a possible double submit.
2. If you are seeing the `/login.do` endpoint without an `/authorize` endpoint request, that is due to a bookmarking scenario.
3. If you are seeing two `/login.do` endpoint with a `/commonauth` endpoint in between them, that is due to a back button click.

If you need to have browser back button support and bookmark support for the SP, you can follow the below steps[1].

1. Open WSO2 IS Management Console and navigate to **Main Menu** → **Registry** → **Browse**
2. Click on **Create text content** and add a resource under `/_system/config/identity/config` with **relyingPartyRedirectUrls** as the resource name.
3. Navigate to the created **relyingPartyRedirectUrls** resource and add a property.
4. Property name should be **Relying party name** and the value should be **redirect URL**
5. For SAML apps, the property name should be the `Issuer Name` of the app and for OAuth apps the property name should be `Client Key` of the app.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/customizing-the-authentication-endpoint/#handling-browser-back-button-and-bookmarked-login-page